# grep command to match the character required

Tags: grep, pcregrep

I am currently using this below command for getting the total snapshot usage of the storage, but this will only show the value in `G` not in `T`:

```
# isi_classic snapshot usage | tail -n 1 | egrep -o "[+-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]([eE][+-])?[0-9]G"
621G
```

Is there any way to match both G & T in one command and the get the exact output?

```
# isi_classic snapshot usage
[snapid 1653, delete pending]                        0     n/a (R)    0.00% (T)
ifs_daily-s1-nov01_20            262G     n/a (R)    0.46% (T)
ifs_weeky-s1-nov01_20            176G     n/a (R)    0.31% (T)

                                               18T     n/a (R)   31.37% (T)
```

Actual output is as shown below

```
 isi_classic snapshot usage | tail -n 1
                                                  621G     n/a (R)    1.08% (T)
```

Comment: Show the output of `isi_classic snapshot usage`. Show your expected output after processing.

Comment: @Sparhawk the output is very big. let me tail it for you.

Comment: I have added the command, sorry missing it.

Comment: Have you tried `egrep "\(G|T\)"`? this way, you would get both G and T.

Comment: yes i tried but no luck.

Comment: it looks to me like you're requiring at least 3 digits before G: `[0-9]+`, `[0-9]`, and `[0-9]`, which can't match `18T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think grep is necessary here, use awk instead,

```
isi_classic snapshot usage | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

But if you insist on using `grep`, change the last `G` to `[GT]` should work for you:

```
isi_classic snapshot usage | tail -1 | egrep -o "[+-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]([eE][+-])?[0-9][GT]"
```